# How can I fix "bad interpreter" error after renaming my django project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

I recently renamed my Django project in Pycharm and now I have many errors associated with Python. From my MAC terminal when I try and run:

$ django-admin startproject mobileproject

or

$ pip install django

I get:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

In Pycharm when I open most of my Django projects I now get:

invalid python interpreter selected for the project

or when i try to install pip:

$ sudo easy_install pip

i get:

sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory

Below was the original structure of my project:

```
---project
       ---project
             ---app 
                   ---models.py
                   ...etc
             ---project
                   ---settings.py
                      ...etc
             ---manage.py
       ---venv
```

To rename my Django project in Pycharm I right clicked on the root folder "project" and selected refactor/rename/rename project. For the rest of the folders I right clicked and selected refactor/rename and I was only given rename directory so I chose that. Below shows how I renamed my project folders.

```
---newproject
       ---newp
             ---newapp 
                   ---models.py
                   ...etc
             ---newp
                   ---settings.py
                      ...etc
             ---manage.py
       ---venv
```

After doing this I have all the errors listed above. I think choosing "rename project" instead of "rename directory" messed things up. But why do I have problems outside of Pycharm when trying to start a new project with django-admin startproject or tell pip to install django? I feel like the Python executable is in the wrong directory but I have no idea. Please Help!

Comment: Recently, homebrew upgraded to Python 3.8 and removed Python 3.7 to make it convenient for you. Welcome to the mess. In order to fix, you have to destroy your vitural envs and recreate them using python 3.8 interpreter.

Comment: Recreate your venv. By renaming the project you basically changed the venv absolute location which is 1) not recommended 2) confuses PyCharm as it still tries to access it with the old path.

Comment: @Melvyn that must be it. So right after renaming my project I installed postgis for some reason that initiated updates of all its dependencies so python was updated to 3.8.

Comment: @JohnMullen That would do it. I've grown accustomed to using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) so I don't depend on the OS version.

Comment: @PavelKarateev thank you for your help. That's my problem. How do I destroy my old venv and recreate my venv? I tried python3 -m venv venv and got:  Error: '/Users/apple/Documents/CS/MobileServiceAvailability/venv/bin/python3' and '/Users/apple/Documents/CS/MobileServiceAvailability/venv/bin/python3' are the same file

Comment: @Melvyn right. so should i try to switch everything over to pyenv or what should i do to destroy all my venv and recreate them with 3.8?

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

Unfortunately PyCharm does not update the venv path containing the Python interpreter when renaming the project/ directory, hence it cannot find the Python interpreter. There is an [issue for this on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32435) too.

### Solution

You have to update the path to the virtual environment manually. To do this open the Interpreter settings with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> | Project <project name> | Python Interpreter** [(see JetBrains Docs)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter), click on **Settings | Show All...**. Then select the venv for your application marked *[invalid]* and click **Edit**. In created modal window you may now update the **Interpreter Path** by replacing the previous directory name with the new one and PyCharm will work like a charm (sorry for the dad joke) again.

### Walkthrough for a simple application

Given a project `pythonProject` with a venv `pythonProject/venv` containing the Python interpreter as follows:

```
pythonProject/
├── src
│   └── app.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate.ps1
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── activate.xsh
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip3
    │   ├── pip-3.9
    │   ├── pip3.9
    │   ├── python -> /usr/bin/python3.9
    │   ├── python3 -> python
    │   ├── python3.9 -> python
    │   ├── wheel
    │   ├── wheel3
    │   ├── wheel-3.9
    │   └── wheel3.9
    ├── lib
    │   └── python3.9
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

Now when we check the Python interpreter settings with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> | Project pythonProject | Python Interpreter** [(see JetBrains Docs)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter) we can see that the interpreter path is set to `path/to/project/pythonProject/venv/bin/python`.

When you now rename the directory (and project) to `renamedProject` using PyCharm`s **Refactor | Rename** option the file structure will look like this:

```
renamedProject/
├── src
│   └── app.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate.ps1
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── activate.xsh
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip3
    │   ├── pip-3.9
    │   ├── pip3.9
    │   ├── python -> /usr/bin/python3.9
    │   ├── python3 -> python
    │   ├── python3.9 -> python
    │   ├── wheel
    │   ├── wheel3
    │   ├── wheel-3.9
    │   └── wheel3.9
    ├── lib
    │   └── python3.9
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

Checking the Python interpreter settings again will show you that the interpreter is invalid now, that is because the path still is `path/to/project/pythonProject/venv/bin/python` but as we renamed the directory the `pythonProject` directory does no longer exist hence this path is in fact invalid (See file tree above).

To resolve this click on **Settings | Show All...** (the cogwheel symbol next to the dropdown menu) within the Python interpreter settings. In the created dialog window select your venv i. e. `[invalid] Python 3.9 (pythonProject)` in this example and click **Edit** (the pen symbol on top of the listing).
There is another window popping up where you can now change the **Intepreter Path**. Replace `pythonProject` with `renamedProject` in the path and accept your changes and you will see that PyCharm immediately recognizes the venv as valid again.